# getting run time error 91 [object variable or with block variable not set]

Tags: vba, adodb

i am trying the code below to pull from access db, but getting error 91, please suggest how to remove the error.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim con As ADODB.Connection

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim strConn As String

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection

    con.Mode = adModeReadWrite

    If con.State = adStateClosed Then

      strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "C:\temp\db2.mdb;Persist    Security Info=False;"

      con.ConnectionString = strConn

      con.Open

    End If

    Dim startRow As Integer

    ***Set rs.ActiveConnection = con***

    rs.Open "select * from tbl_name"
    startRow = 3
    Do Until rs.EOF
       Cells(startRow, 4) = rs.Fields(0).Value
       rs.MoveNext
       startRow = startRow + 1
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, now i got it.. now its working..

Answer (score 3):

You call:

```
rs.ActiveConnection = con
rs.Open
```

without first creating an instance of the RecordSet:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.RecordSet
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error while testing an application.

In my particular case, there was a problem with the Oracle Home used by the application. Therefore, the data source wasn't reachable.