# Run-time error '91' when adding data to a record set

Tags: vb6, runtime-error, ado

I want to insert some information into a database in VB6, but I get runtime error '91'.
My code:

```
    Private sub btn_click()
          Fname = txtFname.text
          Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
          Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Fname") = Fname
          Adodc1.Recordset.Update
    End sub
```

The debuger shows error on: `Adodc.Recordset.AddNew`

Comment: I edited your post to make it more readable. One judgement call I made was to write `Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Fname") = Fname` as one line, instead of the two lines it was. I think this was your original code, before a copy-paste error split the line, but please verify this.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the rest of the code as to where the Adhoc1 variable is created etc...

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592845/getting-run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set) suggests that the RecordSet has not been initialized prior to working with it, but it's hard to be more specific without the code.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime error '91' is [Object variable or With block variable not set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is a slightly confusing way to say that your variable contains `Nothing`.

You either forgot to initialise the `Adodc1` properly, or, and this is more likely, you need to initialise `Adodc1.RecordSet` to something useful (like a `Set Adodc1.RecordSet = New RecordSet` or related) before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

By the way you posted the code, I believe that you will populate a Recordset to insert into the database. Try as follows:

```
sub btn_click()
    dim Adodc1 as adodb.recordset

    set Adodc1 = new adodb.recordset

    Fname = txtFname.text

    Rs.Fields.Append "Fname", adVarChar, 20     'adVarChar = text, followed by the amount of characters

    Adodc1.open()

    Adodc1.Recordset.AddNew
    Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Fname") = Fname
    Adodc1.Recordset.Update
End sub
```